# Output DateTime in that timezone related to the current locale?

Tags: datetime, filter, timezone

Is there a way to loop through a day in 15-minute intervals, with the output of said intervals being localizable? This (cringe-worthy) snippet should help explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<ul>
    {% for hour in 0..23 %}
        {% for min in [0, 15, 30, 45] %}

            {% set foo = [hour, min]|join(':')|date('H:i')|date_modify('+0 days') %}
            <li>{{ foo.localeTime() }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

For me, that snippet results in the unusual error `Method "localeTime" for object "DateTime" does not exist`.

(This question was asked on g+ by Chris Davis. I copied it to SE, as I didn't want to answer it there!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the site's timezone in Craft, but you won't get different timezones for your locales with that (locales != timezones btw.). But what you can do is to use Twig's `|date` filter which allows you to specify a different timezone for the output ([list of supported timezones](https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)). If you create your own `DateTime` object by joining strings, you have to add a timezone here to give the filter a basis for its calculations. Make this match your Craft settings.

The following example works without the Localization package.

```
{# Set locale time to GMT+2 #}
{% set localeTime = "0:00 +0200" %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Local Time</th><th>Sao Paulo</th><th>Manaus</th>
    </tr>

    {% for hour in 0..23 %}
        {% for min in [0, 15, 30, 45] %}

            <tr>
                {# Join time segments in a format supported by strtotime #}
                {% set timeStep = ['+ ', hour, ' hours ', min, ' minutes']|join() %}

                {# Modify the locale time and output in chosen timezone #}
                <td>{{ localeTime|date_modify(timeStep)|date('H:i') }}</td>
                <td>{{ localeTime|date_modify(timeStep)|date('H:i', "America/Sao_Paulo") }}</td>
                <td>{{ localeTime|date_modify(timeStep)|date('H:i', "America/Manaus") }}</td>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

To bring the site's currently requested locale into the game, just do some comparisons on `craft.locale`.

```
{{ craft.locale == 'de-DE' ? localeTime|date('H:i') }}
{{ craft.locale == 'pt-BR' ? localeTime|date('H:i', "America/Sao_Paulo") }}
```