# Do I need to change the date.timezone in php.ini?

Tags: timezone

If I set my timezone in server and in Craft general settings, do I still need to change it in php.ini? And how does Craft handle timezone in those three places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the Craft Documentation about [Date/Time Fields](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/date-time-fields):

> Note: Dates and times [...] are displayed in the site’s timezone, however they get stored in UTC like all other dates in Craft.

Additionally you can also use the [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filter, which allows you to specify a different timezone for the output ([list of supported timezones](https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)). If you want to bind a timezone to a specific site locale (multi-lingual sites), there's a [dedicated Q/A](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/268/) on how to do that.